# 'nd sampleApp' command not found in node js

Tags: node.js

I have installed Node js and trying to run nd sampleApp

D:\www\node>nd sampleApp
'nd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

In environment PATH variable it is there C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: Normally node is invoked like `node SampleApp`. To verify, try `nd --version` and `node --version`

Comment: Can you post your ’package.json’ file content?